# After adding redux to react project, the wepack server is not starting

Tags: reactjs, redux, create-react-app

I'm using facebook/create-react-app bundle. I have recently integrated redux to my existing react project. After integration, the webpack server is not starting giving unCaught error event message.
The log of error is as follows:

```html
0 info it worked if it ends with ok<br><br>
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ] <br><br>
2 info using npm@6.4.1 <br><br>
3 info using node@v8.10.0 <br><br>
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ] <br><br>
5 info lifecycle freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0~prestart: freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0 <br><br>
6 info lifecycle freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0~start: freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0 <br><br>
7 verbose lifecycle freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true <br><br>
8 verbose lifecycle freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/akshay/freetests4u-react-redux/freetests4u-frontend-redux/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0~start: CWD: /home/akshay/freetests4u-react-redux/freetests4u-frontend-redux <br><br>
10 silly lifecycle freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ] <br><br>
11 silly lifecycle freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null <br><br>
12 info lifecycle freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script <br><br>
13 verbose stack Error: freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start` <br><br>
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5) <br><br>
14 verbose pkgid freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/akshay/freetests4u-react-redux/freetests4u-frontend-redux/freetests4u.com-react-js <br><br>
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-36-generic <br><br>
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start" <br><br>
18 verbose node v8.10.0 <br><br>
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1 <br><br>
20 error code ELIFECYCLE <br><br>
21 error errno 1 <br><br>
22 error freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start` <br><br>
22 error Exit status 1 <br><br>
23 error Failed at the freetests4u-frontend@0.1.0 start script. <br><br>
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. <br><br>
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: seems like you don't have one of the  ` 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ` scripts in `package.json`

Comment: I have only start script in package.json & with this script everything was working before integrating redux to the project. I;m using facebook/create-react-app bundle. From where I can get remaining scripts ?

Comment: Try to remove your node_modules folder and run npm install again.

Comment: Removed node_modules & ran npm i. Everything is working now.